# python list transformation from A B C to A A B B C C

Tags: python

I'd like to transform a list ["A", "B", "C"] to a new list ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"]. I can think of an ugly loopy way of doing it but is there a one liner?

Answer (score 2):

I would use itertools.repeat

```
import itertools
n= 2
print([repetition for i in range(10)
           for repetition in itertools.repeat(i,n) ])
```

OUTPUT

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
```

Comment: If you're doing two loops already, you don't need `itertools.repeat`, just use `[i for i in original_input for _ in range(n)]`

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `itertools.chain` with zip to achieve desired result.

```py
from itertools import chain
l = [1,2,3]
list(chain.from_iterable(zip(l,l)))
```

Output:

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about list concatenation with itertools?

```
import itertools
a = ["A", "B", "C"]
c = list(itertools.chain(*[ 2*x for x in a] ))
print(c)
```

OUTPUT

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
```

You could always replace the `2` with a variable.